# Is possible to disable web access to anonymous user with Artifactory?

Tags: artifactory

I've trying to find the answer but after reading a bunch of documentation I think it's not possible, but I would be a nice feature. The problem is I want anyone to access the cached repositories but I don't want them to access the web user interface.

The only way I have figured out is tweaking the nginx configuration to allow access only to certain endpoints like raw repository view. Anyway it has some problems which I've not totally resolved.

Comment: As you mentioned, the only option will be to block it on the proxy level.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to be sure :)

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a [SAML SSO redirect](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/SAML+SSO+Integration) that forces a user to login, and if they fail they are not redirected back to the Artifactory instance. That's the only way I know of that won't let users even look at the front page of Artifactory.

They would get caught on step 3 after an automatic redirect: [SAML SSO Login Process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DD8wP.png)

The obvious downside with this is that you need to have a SAML SSO setup in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the sharing this solution, but I prefer a simpler one. For example a "public" subdomain which is configured to access only the cached repositories and a "private" one which is configured to have also access to the UI.